# Tank Steering Algorithm in ROS

Tags: ros, joy-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm trying to write a ROS node for my mobile robot which is based on a skid-steering system.
I have two motors, one per each side, and each motor can be controlled by using A C/C++ function:

int motor_cmd(MOTOR_channel, VALUE);

where motor_channel is used to choose the motor to control and VALUE is an integer with a range (-100, 0, +100).
Values 0, +100 make the motor spin forward while 0, -100 make the robot spin backward.

I would like to use a bluetooth joypad and write a teleop node to control the robot.
The problem is that I'm not able to figure out how to implement the skid steering motion.

What kind of relation should I write to use the X-Y values which come from the joypad as parameter for my motor_cmd() function?

I mean, if for example I use the joypad to go forward, then X=0, Y=MAX_VALUE and then the function should be:
motor_cmd(1, 100);
motor_cmd(2, 100);
Or if I turn on the spot and so X = MAX_value, Y = - MAX_value, then:
motor_cmd(1, 100);
motor_cmd(2, -100);

How can I implement this algorithm?
Can you help me, please?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226761/tank-steering-algorithm-in-ros/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One very simple implementation of what you're interested in is available here:

- [updateCommand](https://github.com/skohlbr/simple_2wd_robot/blob/master/simple_arduino_control/src/joystick.cpp#L27)
  takes in a speed and angular rate in
  the range [-1.0,1.0] (which can be
  directly mapped to joystick axes) and
  generates left and right wheel
  `int8_t` commands in the range
  [-127,127]. You'd basically just have to substitute the "127" for a "100" as far as I can see.
- A message containing the left and
  right wheel command is sent to an
  Arduino via
  [rosserial_arduino](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino).
  This is then used to apply PWM to the
  motors on the Arduino side via [this
  code in the command
  callback](https://github.com/skohlbr/simple_2wd_robot/blob/master/simple_2wd_control_arduino/firmware/controller.cpp#L31).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-02-16**:
Thank you for your support and answer!
So your suggestion is to write a function like that used on Arduino for my controller?
In this way, speed_in == Y and andRate_in == X?

The solution is to translate that Arduino code into something similar for my controller?